# Solving equation with integration using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, equation, solver, integral

I would like to solve an equation below using MATLAB:

[image]

All the parameters except p are known, so I only need to solve for p. However since I need to consider the sign of the integrand and there is an absolute value sign in it I don't know how to solve it. Could anyone please help? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting question, so I'll give it a stab.  Just out of own curiosity, what equation is this?

```
%This code just displays an error about not enough input arguments in line 4.  I'm still working on fixing this bug, but wanted to provide an update.
function y = yourFunc(m,q,t,p)
    if exist('p') == 0
        syms p
        fun = @(theta,p) ((1/pi) .* sign( 1 - p + (q .* sind(t))) .* (abs(1 - p + (q .* sind(t))) .^ m));
        eqn = (integral(@(theta)fun(theta,p),(-pi/2),(pi/2)) == 1);
        y = solve(eqn,p);
    end
end

function x = runCode()
    x = yourFunc(10,0.5,0:10:90)
end
```

Are your parameters vectors?  I am unsure, but this code should work for elementwise operations anyway.  I also put 1/pi in the integrand since it's a constant and isn't integrated anyway.  Also, a caveat: I have never seen the "sign" function in your integrand so I put it in the code, but I'm not entirely sure what math symbol it is.  I don't have MATLAB in front of me right now, but I think this should work; if you have any problems with it please comment and I'll fix my code.  Good luck with your project!

[Solve Documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html),
[Integral Documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html?s_tid=doc_ta#inputarg_fun)

Comment: Thanks. Actually all the parameters are just scalars (m=10,q=0.5). I tried you code and an error occurs:
Error using integralCalc/finalInputChecks (line 511)
Input function must return 'double' or 'single' values. Found 'sym'.

I don't understand what's the problem here. Maybe the "sign" notation has some problem?

Comment: Probably. What mathematical function did you intend for it to be? It just looked like one word to me. Also, what was the code in line 511? Was that the only error message?

Comment: Actually it occurs at line20 first, which is "eqn = (integral(@(theta)fun(theta,p),(-pi/2),(pi/2)) == 1);" The sign function should be correct but MATLAB somehow cannot identify the whole function.

Comment: Another way I am trying is to use the int function directly, i.e. "eqn = int( ((1/pi) * sign( 1 - p + (q * sin(theta))) * (abs(1 - p + (q * sin(theta))) ^ m)) ,theta,a,b) == 1; " However, MATLAB returns error:Undefined function or variable 'theta'.

Error in Cal_p (line 26)
eqn = int( ((1/pi) * sign( 1 - p + (q * sin(theta))) * (abs(1 - p + (q * sin(theta))) ^ m)) ,theta,a,b) == 1;

Comment: Did you plug in whatever your numbers are directly into the code? If you want to write a script or UDF, initialize them beforehand. If not, just put the numbers straight into the function in the Command Window.